# Independence of transformed RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

We have two continous independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, with respective density functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(y)$. Then

$$f(x,y)=f_1(x)\ f_2(y)$$

where $f_1$ is density of $X$ and $f_2$ is density of $Y$

Then we have some borel functions $z(X)$ and $h(Y)$. My question is whether following formula is true and if it is true - why (could you provide derivation and/or  proof)?:
$$f(z(X),h(Y))=f_1(z(X))\ f_2(h(Y))$$

For instance
$$f(x,y-1)=f_1(x)\ f_2(y-1)$$

or
$$f(2x,y-1)=f_1(2x)\ f_2(y-1)$$

or
$$f(x,y-x)=f_1(x)\ f_2(y-x)$$

where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are respective distributions of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: Yes it is true.

Comment: ;) I forget to ask for proof and/or derivation. edited

Comment: It is because the equation holds for any real valued $x, y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true. It is because the equation holds for any real-valued $x,y$